# How to show that $E(X^k)=npE((Y + 1)^{k-1})$ where $X\sim\mathrm{Bin}(n,p)$ and $Y \sim \mathrm{Bin}(n-1,p)$.

Tags: probability-distributions, binomial-distribution

Show that $$E(X^k)=npE((Y + 1)^{k-1})$$ where $X\sim\mathrm{Bin}(n,p)$ and $Y \sim\mathrm{Bin}(n-1,p)$.

I am looking for suggestions on where to start? Or any resources someone may have.  I am not even sure where to begin.  I have the pdf, cdf, variance, mean and moment generating function of the binomial distribution given to me but I am not sure how to use those.

Comment: Unless you tell us how $X$ is related to $Y$, it is difficult to answer your question.

Comment: I apologize $E(X)$ refers to the variance.

Comment: I still don't get it. So $Y \sim \mathcal{B}(n-1,p)$ but what is $X$?

Comment: How about X~Bin(n,p)

Comment: @AlyssaWallace Are you asking us? You *must* tell us for sure what the relation between the r.v.'s $\;X,\,Y\;$ is .

Comment: X is X~Bin(n,p)

Answer (score 1):

Hint: Fill up details in the following:

With $\;X\sim B(n,p)\;$ and using the identity $\;i\binom ni=n\binom{n-1}{i-1}\;$:

$$E(X^k)=\sum_{i=0}^n i^k\binom ni p^i(1-p)^{n-i}=\sum_{\color{red}{i=1}}^n i^k\binom ni p^i(1-p)^{n-i}=$$

$$=np\sum_{i=1}^n i^{k-1}\binom{n-1}
{i-1} p^{i-1}(1-p)^{n-i}\stackrel{m:=i-1}=np\sum_{m=0}^n (m+1)^{k-1}\binom{n-1}
m p^m(1-p)^{n-1-m}=$$

$$=np\,E\left[(Y+1)^{k-1}\right]\;\;,\;\;\;\text{with}\;\;Y\sim B(n-1,p)$$